# Selecting the JDK for starting Intellij when openjdk-8 is installed

Tags: openjdk, intellij

I have installed openjdk-8 using,

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

and set the path variable but, when I go to create a new maven project in Intellij, it asks me for a JDK. I selected the path /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 and it does not accept this path as a valid path for a JDK.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem got solved, just 'javac' was missing.
Just type  javac in your terminal and it will suggest commands for you.

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless
```

solved my problem